# Ask HR for advice on when to switch roles

Tags: applications, career-switch

I currently work full time in a field (structured finance) in which I'm not interested in staying. However, my long-term goal is to get into quantitative investment management. Recently a recruiter from another company, who deals specifically with this field, downloaded my resume from a job site and I added him on LinkedIn. I also got a call from another HR from that company asking whether I was looking to switch and what all (relevant) skills I had.

Now I got advice from one of my colleagues that if I want to switch, I should do so as early as possible, since it becomes difficult later on. Another guy told me that I should focus on building my skills and then apply. So I want to resolve this thing.

My question- should I ask this recruiter on LinkedIn whether I should switch right now? Of course, I can ask the same question here and get the best possible advice, but my main aim is to let him know that I am indeed interested in switching. Is this a good idea or can it backfire.

My second question is that the HR told me she'd share my profile with the team and see if there are any relevant openings. Should I follow up with her after 1 week, 2 weeks, or not at all?

Comment: [Asking us for our advice on which choice to make is generally considered off topic here](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2695/52713)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all, you need to realize that no HR department, or recruiter gives two damns about your well being. All they care is that the company needs be met, or that they get paid.

The only person interested in your well being is **you**. Get that into your head right now.

That being established, how do you go about potentially switching jobs to something you're more interested in? Well, the first step would be actually engaging with recruiters when they call you.

> **Recruiter:** Hey user324234, my name is Recruiter X, and I was hoping to talk to you about an opportunity to work for a different company. Would you be interested in hearing more? 
>  **You:** While I'm not actively looking for a new job, I'd love to hear about the opportunity you have to offer. Please tell me more!

You shouldn't sound desperate. In fact, one of the things that many recruiters ask you is "Why are you looking to switch workplaces?". You should deflect the question, especially if no details as to the other opportunities have been given:

> I'm not necessarily looking to change employers - I enjoy my job. However, I'm always interested in hearing about new opportunities, and since you called me, and I'm willing to hear you out.

If you like what they have to say, and if the new position sounds like something you might be interested in, **apply**! Nothing is official until you've accepted an offer, and signed the contract, so don't feel guilty about interviewing with potential employers. You stand only to lose if you let opportunities pass  you by.

You can also apply to other positions internally, at which point it doesn't really matter whether you follow up in a week, or two. They'll likely speak to you if they're interested in having you switch over, and this can take many months.

**Suggestion:** Read more questions on Workplace SE to learn more about how to handle recruiters, conversations about expected pay, etc. It's very important that you learn your own self-worth, and how to deal with people who most decidedly do not have your best interest in mind.

Comment: Thank you! So that means I shouldn't follow up with the HR even in 2 weeks because then it would seem that I'm overly eager to switch?

Comment: @user324234 - you worry too much. By all means, follow up with HR in 2 weeks: **Hey, any news from that other team?** However, don't be surprised if they haven't even looked at your resume yet. Your best bet - if you're interested in changing jobs quickly - is to apply to positions outside of your current company. Internally, switching to a different department will depend on politics, team budgets, etc. When you apply to a job posting then all of those hurdles have already been overcome - that's why the job is posted in the first place.